# Browsable REST api for mongo backed model with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, django-rest-framework

I'd like to have a browsable API using django-rest-framework for a rest service using mongodb for the models.
Specifically I'd like to be able to have the url pointing to the actual GET method in the listing of all articles.

I have the following model and serializer:

```
class Article(mongoengine.Document):
    article_id = mongoengine.StringField(required=True)
    author_id = mongoengine.StringField(required=True)
    content = mongoengine.StringField(required=True)

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='article-detail')
    article_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    author_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    content = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        if instance is not None:
            for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
                setattr(instance, k, v)
                return instance

        return Article(**attrs)
```

However when running I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'url'

I tried adding the url attribute to the model but in any case the proper url is not added when the object is serialized.
What would the proper use of serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField for my mongo object Article?

**Edit:**

I think that's almost it thanks to Climax. I changed to

`serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='article-detail', lookup_field='article_id')`

but I get

> {"url": "/article/125/", "article_id": "125"}.

How can I have the DNS name before so that the API is truly browsable?
For example:

> {"url":"http://example.com:1234/article/125/", "article_id":"125"}

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have a look at http://python-eve.org - a REST API for monogodb.  Code is at https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks, great link, didn't knw about eve. However I'm trying to do the same kind of browsable API (self reference url in the object) with the django-rest-framework.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `HyperlinkedIdentityField`. Also in this case the relationship is not many in any direction as this serializer is for a single object.

```
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(many=False, read_only=True, view_name='article-detail')
```

Comment: I think that's almost it! Thank Climax. I changed to `serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='article-detail', lookup_field='article_id')` but I get `{"url": "/article/125/", "article_id": "125"}`. How can I have the DNS name before so that the API is truly browsable? For example `{"url":"http://localhost:1234/article/125/", "article_id":"125"}`.

Comment: Actually all the URLS should be defaulted to absolute. You should get the latest copy since as of v.0.1.4 (April 3, 2013) the notes were...
Improved URL importing: included URL modules now show the full URL with prefix